# Single object of socket IO

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, socket.io

I am trying to create an application based on socket. Looking at the console it can be said that the client to trying to socket server twice; which should not be allowed.

1. Is there any way to stop that?
2. If have modular javascript file where multiple script want to access same socket connection how is that possible?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>socket</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
  var socket = io();
  console.log(typeof socket); // object
  var socket1 = io();
  console.log(socket === socket1); // false
 })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't connect the client to socket twice....
2. A global variable will allow you to access the socket from all your script files

Eg)

```
//you can access this variable from all your scripts
var socket;

$(function(){       
    socket = io();      
    console.log(typeof socket);
})
```

Note that in javascript polluting the global scope with variables and functions is considered bad practice, but that's for another post.

Comment: so the solution comes to create a factory that will a singleton for io .. if am not wrong

Answer (score 0):

The obvious suggestion is to stop having your client connect twice.

But, if you're trying to prevent multiple connections on the server and you really don't want any end user to be able to use more than one window at a time to your web site, then you can prevent another connection once there is already a connection.

The key would be to identify each browser with some sort of unique cookie (user ID or uniquely generated ID number).  You can then implement socket.io authentication that keeps track of which user IDs already have a connection and if a connection is already live, then subsequent attempts to connect will fail the authentication step and will be disconnected.

Supposed you have a cookie set for each browser that's called `userId`.   Then, here's a sample app that makes sure the userId cookie is present and then uses it to deny more than one socket.io connection:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const cookie = require('cookie');

app.use(cookieParser());

let userIdCntr = 1;
const tenDays = 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 10;

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // make sure there's always a userId cookie
    if (!req.cookies || !req.cookies.userId) {
        // coin unique user ID which consists of increasing counter and current time
        let userId = userIdCntr++ + "_" + Date.now();
        console.log("coining userId: " + userId);
        res.cookie('userId', userId, { maxAge: Date.now() + tenDays , httpOnly: true });
    }
    next();
});

app.get('/test.html', function (req, res) {
   console.log('Cookies: ', req.cookies)
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "test.html" );
});

const server = app.listen(80);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

// which users are currently connected
var users = new Set();

// make sure cookie is parsed
io.use(function(socket, next) {
    if (!socket.handshake.headers.cookieParsed) {
        socket.handshake.headers.cookieParsed = cookie.parse(socket.handshake.headers.cookie || "");
    }
    next();
});

// now do auth to fail duplicate connections
io.use(function(socket, next) {
    console.log("io.use() - auth");
    // if no userId present, fail the auth
    let userId = socket.handshake.headers.cookieParsed.userId;
    if (!userId) {
        next(new Error('Authentication error - no userId'));
        return;
    }
    // if already logged in
    if (users.has(userId)) {
        console.log("Failing user " + userId);
        next(new Error('Authentication error - duplicate connection for this userId'));
        return;
    } else {
        console.log("adding user " + userId);
        users.add(userId);
    }
    next();

});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("socket.io connection cookies: ", socket.handshake.headers.cookieParsed);

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log("socket.io disconnect");
        let userId = socket.handshake.headers.cookieParsed.userId;
        users.delete(userId);
    });

    // test message just to see if we're connected
    socket.on("buttonSend", function(data) {
        console.log("buttonSend: ", data);
    });
});
```

---

P.S. You really have to think through the situation where a user with more than one computer (like home/work) leaves one computer on and open to your page and thus connected via socket.io and then attempts to user your site from the other computer.  If you refused the second connection, this will refuse to allow them access from their second computer if the first computer happened to be left open and on.

Comment: Added sample code that denies more than one socket.io connection per browser.

Comment: Actually if i have plugin structure of view components where two or more plugins wants to access socket service then if the socket has already been connected then i want to use the existing connection else i want to create a new connection.

Comment: @Rastafari - So you've included NONE of that actual information in your question?  So, how in the heck do you expect to get an answer to that?  Seriously, either evaluate answers to what you actually put in your question or next time put your REAL question in your question.  We aren't mind readers here.  I answered exactly what you put in your question.  I showed you how to deny multiple connections from the same browser.